# Is there a way to make relation to Set<String> in Room?

Tags: android-room

Assume tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (id INT, name VARCHAR(255))
CREATE TABLE user_roles (user_id INT REFERENCES users(id), role_name VARCHAR(255))
```

Entity in Room:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
  @PrimaryKey
  val id: Int,
  val roles: Set<String>  // want it from role_name column
)
```

Second entity (if needed):

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "user_roles")
data class UserRole(
  val user_id: Int,
  val role_name: String
)
```

DAO

```kotlin
@Dao
interface UserDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
  fun getAllUsers(): Flow<List<User>>
}
```

This will not compile because SQLite doesn't support collections. Is there any way to map the `role_name` from `user_roles` to `roles` property of User entity? Can Room do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Room has automatic support for that requirement. Instead you could do a custom query to achieve that.

Refer to this example of how to do one, and adapt according to your requirements.

`getAllUsersWithRoles` returns flow of list of `UserWithRoles`. Query joins users and user_roles tables and maps results to `UserWithRolesResult` class.

`fromResult` takes list of `UserWithRolesResult` and maps it to list of `UserWithRoles`

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
  @Transaction
  @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
  fun getAllUsersWithRoles(): Flow<List<UserWithRoles>>

  companion object {
    private fun fromResult(result: List<UserWithRolesResult>) : List<UserWithRoles> {
      val map = result.groupBy { it.userId }.mapValues { it.value.map { it.roleName }.toSet() }
      return map.map { UserWithRoles(it.key, it.value) }
    }
  }
}

data class UserWithRoles(
  val userId: Int,
  val roles: Set<String>
)

data class UserWithRolesResult(
  val userId: Int,
  val roleName: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This will not compile because SQLite doesn't support collections.

Room however does.

Consider the following working Demo based upon your code

- note the comments and modifications
- run on the main thread for brevity
- the POJO **UserWithRoles** is the main inclusion that uses a **Set**, which is populated/used

:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
    /* roles would be effectively trying to store what is stored elsewhere */
    //val roles: Set<String>  // want it from role_name column !! Wrong place see UserWithRoles
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "user_roles",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = User::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["user_id"]
        )
    ]
    )
data class UserRole(
    @PrimaryKey
    /* In Room and Entity MUST have a primary key */
    /* if user_id were a primary key then many UserRoles per User would not be allowed as
        a primary key is implicitly UNIQUE. Hence dummy_id
     */
    val dummy_id: Long?=null,
    val user_id: Int,
    val role_name: String
)

data class UserWithRoles(
    @Embedded
    val user: User,
    @Relation(entity = UserRole::class, parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "user_id" )
    val roles: Set<UserRole>
)
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(user: User): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(userRole: UserRole): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    fun getAllUsers(): /*Flow<*/List<UserWithRoles>/*>*/
}

@Database(entities = [User::class,UserRole::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getUserDao(): UserDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

and some Activity Code to demonstrate:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: UserDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getUserDao()

        dao.insert(User(10,"Fred"))
        dao.insert(User(11,"Mary"))
        dao.insert(User(12,"Jane"))

        dao.insert(UserRole(user_id = 10, role_name = "Role1"))
        dao.insert(UserRole(user_id = 10, role_name = "Role2"))
        dao.insert(UserRole(user_id = 10, role_name = "Role3"))

        dao.insert(UserRole(user_id = 11, role_name = "Role4"))

        for (uwr in dao.getAllUsers()) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (r in uwr.roles) {
                sb.append("\n\tRole is ").append(r.role_name)
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","User is ${uwr.user.name} and has ${uwr.roles.size} roles. They are ${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

When run then the log includes:-

```
D/DBINFO: User is Fred and has 3 roles. They are 
        Role is Role3
        Role is Role2
        Role is Role1
D/DBINFO: User is Mary and has 1 roles. They are 
        Role is Role4
D/DBINFO: User is Jane and has 0 roles. They are
```